# Caching a vertex array object in Haskell, when rendering

Tags: haskell, opengl, caching, io, shader

Ok, the title is terrible, but I'm not sure how else to convey my problem at a glance.

Currently, in my display callback when rendering using OpenGL, a function called `render` can be called on different types of geometry, which are stored as lists of vertices, normals, and/or texture coordinates (as a single, pair or triple, depending on which one is used).

When I render, I flatten this out to be `[GLfloat]`, so that I can pass it to a VBO and VAO. I then store the VAO, and render that. Usually, this is done in the initialisation stage, and then transformations and such are applied in the display callback, but if a user wanted to do this in the display callback instead, it flattens the geometry EVERY time, and I set up the VBO, VAO, and attribute variables ever render pass. This is obviously making it super slow if there're any objects (geometry) in the display callback.

What I want to do, is if it is an object, to flatten it, etc to a VAO, and then the next time it is encountered, use the VAO. I've got a constructor which takes the VAO as an argument of the same type, so it can be comfortably replaced.

`compile` does the same as render, except returns a `CompiledDrawable` which holds the VAO.

I'm looking to use something like:

```
getObject :: Drawable -> IORef Drawable
getObject drawable = unsafePerformIO $ compile drawable
```

The only problem is, there isn't just one of these, I need to be able to do it for all my objects and have their own references. Any ideas?

Comment: This is way past my skill-grade, but you may not need IORefs. If Haskell is not already memoizing those things for you (which it only does occasionally at a very high-level, as far as I know), you can potentially allocate a Data.Array or Data.Map for the entire set of VAOs, if you have an ID for each possible vertex-array-object. Both of these structures are lazy, so when you create the structure it merely has thunks, and you don't access the elements of the structures until you absolutely need them: thus the array/map does exactly what you're trying to do with caching.

Comment: Well, I ended up making using a map, but I couldn't use the VAO ids, since I had nowhere to reference it to each object. I ended up making a `IORef (Map (DObject, GLState) Drawable)` and modify the map anytime a new pair comes in.

Comment: It's not the best approach since DObject and GLState are annoying things to use as keys, but they're the only discernable things to relate it. It feels like I'm normalising a damn database.

Comment: Hi @Gentatsu, I ran into a similar problem. Did you find an answer?

Comment: Hey, not a foolproof way that fits everything, but there's a couple ways of doing it. Like I did before with the unique object that identifies each object for geometry and attributes/uniforms set, or use the VAO. The first one means recording A LOT more data potentially, strict or lazy you might end up having to go through a lot of stuff, but then if you have two objects with the same geom/attr/uniforms, you don't have duplicates. The second way is to record the VAO ID as an IORef in the object, and check it when you render, if it's the first time, record it, else just recover that VAO.

Comment: The issue with that, is that if it has all the same info, it'll treat it as a unique object. Personally, I think the second approach is better, unless you've got loooads of objects (idk how many would make it less viable) that are the same, such that switching the VAO is slower than checking if they're equal. Even then, I'm not sure if it would ever be, as you'd have more objects to check anyway. Hope this helps!